# oralce date filter not returning the expected record

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, nsdateformatter

I have an oracle DATE column and the value of a particular record for the column is

```
16/10/2005 11:13:34 AM.
```

Now I am putting in a filter like this where the filter string is passed in from the front end.

```
date_col between to_date('16-10-2005','DD-MM-YYYY') and to_date('16-10-2005','DD-MM-YYYY')
```

It returns zero records. Why is this happening? I was thinking oracle would return all records that have a date of 16/10/2005 irrespective of the time.
Do i need to pass in thetime also/From the front end, I only get date and not time.

Comment: http://jeffkemponoracle.com/2012/06/22/date-is-not-a-date/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
date_col between to_date('16-10-2005','DD-MM-YYYY') 
     and to_date('16-10-2005','DD-MM-YYYY')
```

will only return `DATE` values of midnight on October 16, 2005.  If you want to fetch data for any time on October 16, 2005

```
date_col between to_date('16-10-2005','DD-MM-YYYY') 
             and to_date('16-10-2005 23:59:59','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

will do it.  So would

```
date_col between to_date('16-10-2005','DD-MM-YYYY') 
             and to_date('17-10-2005','DD-MM-YYYY') - interval '1' second
```

If you fail to subtract that second, you'll also end up pulling rows that have a `date_col` value of midnight on October 17, 2005.

You could also apply a `trunc` function to your `date_col`

```
trunc(date_col) = date '2005-10-16'
```

but that would prevent a standard index on `date_col` from being used.  You would generally need to create a function-based index on `trunc(date_col)`

```
CREATE INDEX idx_trunc_date_col
    ON table_name( trunc(date_col) );
```

Comment: Thanks as always for going the extra mile. Beautiful.

Comment: This would work in the vast majority of situations, but if you really need to be 100% sure that you get all records, oracle stores fractions of a second - so you need to be aware that all but the (trunc) example would exclude records 100th of a second before midnight.  I prefer the >= and < method for this reason, and the execution plan is identical.

Comment: @FionaT - Oracle does not store fractions of a second in a `DATE` column.  It may store fractional seconds in a `timestamp` column depending on how that column is defined.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - you need a time element.

to_date('16-10-2005','DD-MM-YYYY') defaults to midnight - so to retrieve all records on 16/10/05 you could use

```
date_col >= to_date('16-10-2005','DD-MM-YYYY')
and date_col < to_date('17-10-2005','DD-MM-YYYY')
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the last date the next day minus 1 second...

```
date_col between to_date('16-10-2005','DD-MM-YYYY') 
    and to_date('16-10-2005 23:59:59','DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS')
```

Comment: That would include records with a date of midnight on 17th

Comment: @FionaT I'm always off-by-one